# Does Javascript has an effect to the printed version of the site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

Simple question, don't have a printer around, My client is asking if the hiddent elements of the web page(items that show up on click) will be printed out on the paper or will it be hidden?

Answer (score 6):

You can provide a separate css file for print media, so you can decide exactly what is visible and what is not when printing. eg

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" href="printStyle.css">
```

Without a specific css file, most browsers will simply use the screen css file for printing as well.

Answer (score 5):

Easy way:
Look at the **print-preview** of your browser (or install a **PDF-printer**) and see.

Harder way:
Check the **CSS** of the elements (might want to use Firebug to see all the properties). Don't forget the **@media** print CSS.

Comment: *PDF printer* Ubuntu can do that :P

Answer (score 1):

Open the page in Firefox and click on Print Preview.

Whatever you see is what would get printed. Just try this SO page.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the page currently looks like, plus `@media print` styles, browser scaling and browser removal of backgrounds (if applicable) will be what is printed. Try print preview to see what it'll look like.

Answer (score 0):

It will not

Likewise you can do

```
 @media print { 'your elements ref' {display:none;visibility:hidden}}
```

or even better use color/background-color white/transparent ;o)